# How to see update details

Tags: release-loki, updates, appcenter

Prior to Loki, you were shown details about what was getting updated.  Is there a way in Loki AppCenter to see the specifics prior to clicking the update button?

Answer (score 2):

As for now, this should be a feature request for now as there is no such possibility.

However, as a workaround you can check applicable updates with `apt list --upgradable` in a terminal window:

```
user@host:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
linux-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.51.54 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.47.50]
linux-headers-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.51.54 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.47.50]
linux-image-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.51.54 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.47.50]
linux-libc-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0-51.72 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0-47.68]
linux-tools-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 4.4.0-51.72 all [upgradable from: 4.4.0-47.68]
linux-tools-virtual/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.51.54 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.47.50]
```

Answer (score 1):

One may fire up a terminal and issue a command prior to updating from app-center:
sudo tail -f  /var/log/apt/history.log /var/log/apt/term.log

Then you will see what is going on

Comment: Actually I think this is only useful to check what has been done not to check _before_ clicking on the update button.